# Font and style of axes labels

Tags: plotting, labeling

In the plot below, the "l" letter in the axes labels looks like number one also the "x" in the numerator and denominator of the x-axis are not the same?

```
 Plot[{x, Sin[x]/2}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x l/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)", 
   "G l/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(0\)]\)"}, ImageSize -> 260, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", , Black, Bold},
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.8}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Green, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Black, 
    Dashed, Thick}, {Blue, Dashed, Thick}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}, 
    None}, {{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}, None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can style the fonts in the front end using the usual shortcuts (e.g. on Windows CTRL+i will give you italic, etc). To prevent the "el" letter from looking like a "1" number, you may want to show it italic.

```
Plot[{x, Sin[x]/2}, {x, 0, 3},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {
   Text@Style["x l/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)", Bold, Italic],
   Text@Style["G \!\(\*StyleBox[\"l\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\) / \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(0\)]\)", Bold]
 },
 ImageSize -> 260, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.8}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Green, Thick}, {Red, Thick}, {Black, Dashed, Thick}, {Blue, Dashed, Thick}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}, None}, {{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3}, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much! it works :-)